# How to encode URL parameters for REST API call?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, url-parameters

I have to create a some url parameters that I use in a REST API call. I'm using Angularjs 1.4.2 and a form to pass the parameters to a service function, which builds the parameters and makes the $http.post call to the API.  I created a plunker for the parameter building piece.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.2" data-semver="1.4.2" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.2/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="mainCtrl">
      testData is: {{testData}}<p></p>
      The data is: {{data}}
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

**script.js**

```
// Code goes here
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope, $httpParamSerializerJQLike) {
    //Create JavaScript object.
   var testData = {};

    //Load the object with the same data as data.
    testData = loadTestData(testData);
    console.log("testData is: " + JSON.stringify(testData));
    //testData is: {"username":"james@gmail.com","password":"myPassword","grant_type":"password","env":"dev"}

    //Use stringify to make it into a JSON string.
    $scope.testData = $httpParamSerializerJQLike(JSON.stringify(testData));
    //Decoded testData
    //={"username":"james@gmail.com","password":"myPassword","grant_type":"password","env":"dev"}

    $scope.data = $httpParamSerializerJQLike({
      "username":"james@gmail.com",
      "password":"myPassword",
      "grant_type":"password",
      "env": "dev"
    });


    function loadTestData(testData){
      testData.username = "james@gmail.com";
      testData.password = "myPassword";
      testData.grant_type = "password";
      testData.env = "dev";
      return testData; 
    }
});
```

I put hardcoded data into a variable called data, then use $httpParamSerializerJQLike to serialize data.  With my hardcoded data, called data, everything works fine and I get the HTTP 200 success response from the API call in my actual code.

So I created a JavaScript object called testData for the parameters, turned it from an object to JSON using JSON.stringify, then used httpParamSerializerJQLike to serialize the data.  However, the hardcoded (data) doesn't look like the testData and it's throwing HTTP 401 errors.

I created a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/9nhJtiUaVtKUnjjEmQfr) to try and see what is happening.  In the plunker, here is what the hardcoded (data) ends up like:

> The data is:
>   env=dev&grant_type=password&password=myPassword&username=james@gmail.com
>
> Here is what the testData ends up like: testData is:
>   =%7B%22username%22:%22james@gmail.com%22,%22password%22:%22myPassword%22,%22grant_type%22:%22password%22,%22env%22:%22dev%22%7D

Decoded testData is obviously not right for a URL string;

> ="username":"james@gmail.com","password":"myPassword","grant_type":"password","env":"dev"}

Why is this and do I have to manually create a function to create the URL string or is there another solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have to give the JavaScript object to the function "httpParamSerializerJQLike()", not string as you are doing JSON.Stringify(testData).

Try this, it worked for me:

```
    $scope.testData = $httpParamSerializerJQLike(testData);
```

Now the output is:

```
testData is: env=dev&grant_type=password&password=myPassword&username=james@gmail.com
The data is: env=dev&grant_type=password&password=myPassword&username=james@gmail.com
```

Comment: `JSON` is a string format. Do you mean JavaScript object?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.entries()` get an array of arrays containing properties and values of a JavaScript object, iterate the array with `Array.prototype.map()`, chain `.join()` with parameter `""` to create a query string

```js
let o = {
  "username": "james@gmail.com",
  "password": "myPassword",
  "grant_type": "password",
  "env": "dev"
};

let props = Object.entries(o);
let params = `?${props.map(([key, prop], index) => 
                `${key}=${prop}${index < props.length -1 ? "&" : ""}`
             ).join("")}`;

console.log(params);
```

Comment: I'm using ES5, so let isn't an option, but I upvoted because I liked your code.  Thanks!

Comment: The code does not do proper [percent encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding). For example, `james@gmail.com` should be encoded `james%40gmail.com`.

Comment: @georgeawg What do you suggest adjusting? Using `encodeURIComponent()`? `fetch()` passes the parameters as query string parameters

Comment: @georgeawg `encodeURIComponent(params)` results in `james%40gmail.com`, the dot character is not encoded as `%40`.

Comment: `%40` is the percent encoding of `@`. The dot `.` character is an unreserved character and does not need percent encoding.

Comment: @georgeawg Why does `fetch()` not complain and pass the expected key, value pairs as part of the request query string?

Comment: @georgeawg Do you have the answer for the question at previous comment?

Answer (score 0):

> I'm using Angularjs 1.4.2 and a form to pass the parameters to a service function, which builds the parameters and makes the `$http.post` call to the API.

The is no need to manually encode url parameters with the [$http service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http). Simply use the `params` property of the config object:

```
var params = {name: "joe"};
var config = { params: params };

var httpPromise = $http.post(url, data, config);
```

See the encoding done with this [DEMO on PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/Tmvwgwu90q5jieSfAVSh?p=preview).

Comment: Where do you use `encodeURIComponent()` at your own Answer?

Comment: The [percent encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) is handled by the $http service.

Comment: The same is not true for `fetch()`? You did not answer the question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45249692/how-to-pass-url-parameters-for-rest-api-call/45249768?noredirect=1#comment77466343_45249768

Comment: That does not answer the question. `fetch()` passes the correct query string parameters when `params` variable at Answer is concatenated to URL.